# I can't move the curser with the up and down and side to side keys in Terminal

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

I must be missing something here. I have worked with terminal before.
I am trying to change "true" to false and the arrow keys are not moving the cursor to do this.
Please help me .
Thanks.[terminal picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIwOq.png)

Thanks to all for your help. Is there somewhere to mark this as solved?

I'm sorry but how do I "accept" an answer? I don't mean to seem dumb here.......

Comment: *Is there somewhere to mark this as solved?* yes - please accept one of the answers - I’ve upvoted them both as good answers, but it’s good to accept one of them.

Answer (score 1):

Your previous commands are history. The cursor can only move on the current line. However, you can use the up and down arrows to access your history on the current line.

The cursor will only move on the current line. To access history, you can use the up and down arrow to page through your previous commands. So from the current blank line with the last two commands shown in your screenshot, you would use the up arrow twice to first show the gsettings command and then you would use the right arrow key to edit your previous command (I assume you want to change `get` to `set` and then set the value as true at the end of the line).

Comment: Your current line is blank in the screenshot so there is nowhere to move.

Answer (score 1):

You are indeed missing something here. The first "true" on your screen dump is the output of a command. You did not type it yourself.

The second "true" is a command you type at the prompt. Learn about it with the command `man true`.

<kbd>Arrow Up</kbd> will recall previous commands you exeuted. Press it one time, and the command `true` is on the editing line, press it twice, and the `gsettings` command is on the editing line.

What you really want to do, I guess, is recalling your `gsettings` command, then changing `get` to `set` and adding `false` on the end of the line to turn the setting off ("set") rather than reading out its current value ("get").